# DataAccessException when implementing WITH RECURSIVE query using SQLITE and jOOQ

Tags: java, sqlite, jooq

I am currently using jOOQ 3.13.4 and SQLite in order to perform a recursive query. I am also restricted to only using Java 8 compatible versions of jOOQ. My general table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    ID                  GUID(32)        UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID            GUID(32)        group (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

CREATE TABLE map (
    GroupID          GUID(32)    NOT NULL REFERENCES group(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Path             TEXT        NOT NULL
);
```

My goal is to select one `group` by its `group.ID` and retrieve a list of all `map.Path` values that are associated with the nested `groups`.

I am currently using the [WITH RECURSIVE tutorial](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-recursive-clause/) provided by jOOQ and have code very similar to the one described in the tutorial. The `{some_value}` is an `id` I can pass in as a parameter to determine the `group` that I want all nested `paths` for.

```
Table<?> table = table(select(GROUP.ID.as(field(name("id"), UUID)),
                              GROUP.PARENTID.as(field(name("parentId"), UUID)),
                              MAP.PATH.as(field(name("path"), VARCHAR)))
                        .from(GROUP)
                        .join(MAP)
                        .on(MAP.GROUPID.eq(GROUP.ID))).as("table");                                                                          

Field<UUID> id = table.field(name("id"), UUID);
Field<UUID> parentId = table.field(name("parentId"), UUID);
Field<String> path = table.field(name("path"), VARCHAR);

CommonTableExpression<?> cte = name("tree").fields("id", "path")
                                                   .as(select(id,
                                                              path).from(table)
                                                                   .where(id.eq({some_value}))
                                                                   .union(select(id,
                                                                                 path).from(table)
                                                                                      .join(table(name("tree")))
                                                                                      .on(parentId.eq(field(name("tree",
                                                                                                                 "id"),
                                                                                                            UUID)))));

return ctx.withRecursive(cte)
          .selectFrom(cte)
          .fetch(field(name("tree", "path"), VARCHAR), String.class)
```

However when running the method that contains the above code I receive the following exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with recursive tree(id, path) as (select * from (select "table".id, "table".path from (select group.ID as id, group.ParentID as parentId, map.Path as path from group join map on map.GroupID = group.ID) as "table" where "table".id = ?) x union select * from (select "table".id, "table".path from (select group.ID as id, group.ParentID as parentId, map.Path as path from group join map on map.GroupID = group.ID) as "table" join tree on "table".parentId = tree.id) x) select tree.id, tree.path from tree]; [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (recursive reference in a subquery: tree)

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (recursive reference in a subquery: tree)
```

This exception makes me think that you cannot reference table "tree" within the declaration of "tree" for SQLite, but it seems to be able to do so in the tutorial.
Is there a caveat with jOOQ and SQLite for `WITH RECURSIVE`? Or is my aliased table a source of the problem?

Comment: Does the problem still appear with jOOQ 3.15.2?

Comment: @LukasEder I unfortunately cannot use a 3.15.* because I am restricted to using Java 8. I'll update the question to include that information.

Comment: jOOQ 3.15 still supports Java 8, see here: https://www.jooq.org/download/versions. You could just quickly use the free trial to validate this.

Comment: @LukasEder Yes I am still receiving the same DataAccessException

Comment: This works perfectly well for me using jOOQ 3.15.2 and SQLite 3.36.0.3 (via the xerial jdbc driver). On my end, the `group` table is quoted as `"group"` - so you might still not have the right vversion of jOOQ on your classpath.

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, I did not inject the jar properly initially and an upgrade does resolve the issue. I just upgrade to 3.14.9 to prevent cascading changes to my other dependencies since the related issue seemed to be resolved as early as 3.14.9: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11582